# Referencing Native Libraries within NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-kernel, android-native-library

I am trying to reference native libraries from within an NDK project using CMAKE, but I am not having much luck. My first attempt was to simply add the include for the native library I was interested in. (for example)

```
#include <multinetwork.h>
```

However, that didn't work it simply said file not found. So, would it be something I put in the CMakeList.txt? Just to be clear I want to reference native library methods/classes DIRECTLY from my C++ code in my NDK project.

P.S: (READING PAST HERE ISN'T NESSASARY IT JUST ADDS MORE COLOR ON WHAT I AM GOING AFTER) I feel like I should share my true objective is to gain access to things not allowed through the application framework. I want to override/use classes in the native libraries that I am not given access to. I am hoping I don't have to recompile kernal to do this.

Comment: Please fix typo in the title: ```Refencing -> Referencing```.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
#include <android/multinetwork.h>
```

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for it being something this stupid. When I use this site (https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/networking) for a reference I don't see a package structure or any super/sub classes listed. Is there a better site to use, or once again am I missing something simple?

Comment: Mentioned link it is exactly the original source, but it is sad to say that there are also inaccuracies happen for example like in given case.